# Help with a simple number theory proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove, that no matter how we give $8$ three-digit numbers, we can always choose $2$ of them, which we write next to each other, that six-digit number will be divisible with $7$.
Example: I have $123$, and $456$ and I can make $123456$ or $456123$ as a $6$-digit number.

Edit: I think it has to do something with 8. From 8 numbers you can always choose 2 which are congruent to each other(mod7), and these 2 numbers, wrote down as 6 digit number are good.

Answer (score 8):

Hints:

1. $1000\equiv -1\mod 7$
2. $8>7$
3. Pigeon Hole Principle

Answer (score 0):

Using Julian Aguirre’s hints, in case this is helpful to others...

There are 7 possible remainders upon division by 7. If we have 8 numbers then by the pigeonhole principle and the fact that $8 > 7$, at least two of these numbers must share their remainder. Call these two numbers $a$ and $b$. Since they are three digit numbers, writing them next to each other forms the number $1000a + b$. Since $1000 \equiv -1 \pmod 7$, the remainder of $1000a$ is ‘minus one times’ the remainder of $a$. The remainder of $1000a + b$ is the sum of the remainders of $1000a$ and $b$ which now clearly is zero. So this number is divisible by 7.

The final two steps follow from the elementary facts that if $a \equiv p \pmod n$ and $b \equiv q \pmod n$ then $a + b \equiv p + q \pmod n$ and $ab \equiv pq \pmod n$.